# How to correctly use GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer to prevent missing type id property @class

Tags: java, spring, redis, jackson, spring-data-redis

I have been trying for several days to figure out how to properly configure the GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer to work with my Java Pojos. Im using **spring-data-redis-2.3.3.RELEASE**. I have achieved many different results in different configurations but none of which work. Below is what seems to me to be the most correct configuration for what I am trying to achieve based on my research.

```
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,Object> jsonRedisTemplate() {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().failOnEmptyBeans(false)
            .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
            .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .modules(new JavaTimeModule()).build();

    objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(objectMapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator(),ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    objectMapper.registerSubtypes(Game.class, String.class, MediaList.class, EventScorecard.class, MainScorecard.class, EventStatus.class, EventAttributes.class, ScoreCard.class);

    final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());

    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper));
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper));
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper));

    return redisTemplate;
}
```

Using this RedisTemplate with the objectMapper and GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer always results in the following error

> Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class'

One thing I noticed with this config is if I pass in `new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)` to the `setKeySerializer` then the error does not occur and an empty `[]` gets returned.

I've read a ton of other stackoverflow questions at this point as well as web pages but I have not found anything that really differs dramatically from what I have so I don't know where to turn at this point. I am using **Jackson v2.13.3**. Any direction here will be greatly appreciate.

**Edit**

I'm noticing with the below configuration that uses `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` instead of `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` that everything works. However, also notice I had to directly pass in a specific type `Game.class` into `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer`  to get things to work for only this specific object. What I want to have is a single RedisTemplate that can work for all of my classes.

```
    @Bean
public RedisTemplate<String,Object> jsonRedisTemplate() {

    final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
            .addModules(new JsonOrgModule()).build();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY, true);
    
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Game.class);
    jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

    return redisTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to use it correctly? I'm struggling with the same problem. I'm so frustrated :(

Comment: I did figure out a solution. I will try to get back to you in the next few days.

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to solve my problem. My pain point was not setting a default implementation in the `@JsonTypeInfo` on my DTOs. 
But maybe you could post your solution anyway, I think that would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING worked for me after a long research. [Reference](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3512#issuecomment-1150913172)

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Object> reactiveRedisTemplate(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(objectMapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator(), ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

    RedisSerializer<Object> redisSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper);
    RedisSerializationContext<String, Object> context = RedisSerializationContext
            .<String, Object>newSerializationContext(RedisSerializer.string())
            .value(redisSerializer)
            .hashValue(redisSerializer)
            .build();

    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(connectionFactory, context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This was a very helpful example!